# Update Specific Attributes or Fields

Tags: php, yii

PROBLEM 1:

When I try to `save()` any Yii Model, it **updates** all fields in the row.
The problem is: When I try to save model users, even if has no PASSWORD to update, it get the database value(already hashed) and hash again.
How can I do to YII only update fields that I want?

Code:

```
$user = Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
$user->ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$user->save();
```

Users.php (Model):

```
public function beforeSave() {
    if (!empty($this->password))
        $this->password=$this->hashPassword($this->password);
    return true;
}
```

---

PROBLEM 2:

I have an API that can create USERS.
API Tutorial: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/175/how-to-create-a-rest-api/

When I have crypter_password in the database, instead password, I got the error: `Parameter password is not allowed for model Users`, because the API validate parameters using `$model->hasAttribute()`.
How can I fix the API `actionCreate` to allow custom parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventhough the other answers listed here are not wrong, they are definitely not really developer friendly and it's extremely easy to forget to add the attributes to the save line.

Here is a developer friendly way of working.

In your model, add the following attribute:

```
private $_aAttributesBackup;
```

In this variable, we will store an exact copy of the current model. To do this, the following afterFind method needs to be added:

```
public function afterFind()
{
    $this->_aAttributesBackup = $this->attributes;
}
```

Almost there. At this point, the model will store all of his attributes in the attributesBackup field which makes it easier to compare. To make it easier, we also need a method that will check if the specified attribute has a backup value. We do this by adding the following code into our model:

```
public function getOriginalAttribute($sAttribute)
{
    if ($this->_aAttributesBackup)
    {
        return $this->_aAttributesBackup[$sAttribute];
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Now, how about checking if the password has been changed? Simple, by adding the following beforeSave code:

```
public function beforeSave()
{
    if ($this->getOriginalAttribute('password') != $this->password)
    {
        $this->password = sha1($this->password);
    }
    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

Et voila. Now everytime you execute the code $Model->save(); the system will check if the password has been changed, If the password is changed, it will hash it again, if it is not changed, it won't be hashed again.

Comment: for this case, you dont need to back up all the attributes, backing up just password should be enough. also, you need to do the same hash on the password before doing the check.

Comment: true :-), but why would you need to do the same hash? We are not un-hashing the password after we've retrieved it from the database, are we?

Comment: no we dont, but it looks like the password is a input from user.. so we need to hash it again before comparing

Comment: Wouldn't you need to check for a blank password field too? If no password was supplied, but a `$_POST['Users']['password']` was posted and added to the attributes when massively assigned, then `if ($this->getOriginalAttribute('password') != $this->password)` will return true?

Comment: Thank you for the input, I had not thought that way!

Comment: There are two valid options for use: Save the database as crypter_password and validate as password (have the problem in the code of the API yet) or this method. What do you think best?

Comment: by using this method no database changes are required which means that the shielding between the model and the database layer remains intact and both can still be seen as seperate things

Answer (score 1):

According to Yii's doc: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#save-detail

```
public boolean save(boolean $runValidation=true, array $attributes=NULL)
```

$attributes - array - list of attributes that need to be saved. Defaults to null, meaning all attributes that are loaded from DB will be saved.

You can pass in an array of fields that you want to save.

Comment: Should I use all SAVE () of my system with the correct parameters to be changed?

Comment: @LucianoNascimento see my answer with description with code you can test with.

Comment: I have read and tested, and it worked perfectly. Just wonder if it is correct to always use the SAVE () with the parameters to create a secure application.

Comment: @LucianoNascimento No usually you dont have to.

Comment: In all my UserController functions I need to use save w/ parameters or I get problem with the password hash. Do you have a better idea to fix that problem?

Comment: @LucianoNascimento check this out - http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/3886-jformvalidate-extension-validate-required-field-even-when-it-shouldnt/page__p__21875#entry21875

Comment: I tried it before but I not used due a problem with my API. I updated my original post, please check the Problem 2.

Comment: Please check my provided answer

Answer (score 0):

`Save ()` inserts a row into the database table if its `isNewRecord` property is `true`. Otherwise, *it will update the corresponding row in the table* (usually the case if the record is obtained using one of those 'find' methods.)

What you have to do is update specific field so you can use [`SaveAttributes`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#saveAttributes-detail) and it accepts the array of string values that have been updated for example demo code is as follow

```
$user = Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
$user->ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$user->SaveAttributes(array('ip'));
```

Comment: SaveAttributes validate the model too?

Comment: @AfnanBashir "Also note that this method does neither attribute filtering nor validation."